# Is it a mark against Esau that he is a hunter?

Tags: genesis, literary-criticism

In Genesis 25:27 we are told of Esau that he was a skillful hunter, which is contrasted with the character of Jacob:

> When the boys grew up, Esau was a skillful hunter, a man of the field, while Jacob was a quiet man, dwelling in tents.

Certainly this characterization of Esau as a hunter is necessary in driving the plot forward both in the present story as well as in the later deception of Issac. However, in light of [David's answer regarding the characterization of Nimrod](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/24888), is the fact that he is a hunter also intended to put Esau in a negative light, particularly in comparison to Jacob?

Comment: I think what’s really a mark is not the hunter but is that Esau seems to have nephilim genetics. What human do you know of has hair like a goat, let alone on the smooth part of his neck. You touched a young kid or you touched Esau and you would not have noticed a difference. People back then seemed to know who had nephilim traits “And the skins of the young goats she put on his hands and on the smooth part of his neck.”
‭‭Genesis‬ ‭27:16‬ ‭ESV‬‬ where did those genetics come from? “The first came out red, all his body like a hairy cloak, so they called his name Esau.”
‭‭Genesis‬ ‭25:25‬ ‭ESV

Comment: @MrConstantin I don't think that's an idea you could've got from the Bible. And if Esau had nephilim genes, then so too did Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob.

Comment: Genesis 6:1-6 speak of the sons of G-d which I tie into Deu 32:8 DDS &LXX and Also Psalms 82,89 making reference not to humans. That is all in the Bible, not using any extrabiblical sources. Also you are assuming that it was in the patriarchs. It is believed to be passed on the X chromosome, so while a father can give his daughter an X chromosome if he has a son it is necessary for it to come from the mother. I don’t ascribe to the Augustinian interpretation sons of G-d being humans, there are too many issues with that interpretation when plugged into Scripture.

Comment: Does the epithet *skillful* usually carry any negative connotation ?

Comment: @Lucian They use different Hebrew words, but Jeremiah 4:22 has "skillful in evil" and Ezekiel 21:31 has "brutish men, skillful to destroy" neither of which seem positive. But perhaps you could develop your comment into an answer?

Comment: @Soldarnal: I said *usually*. And would hunting (for food) be normally considered an evil activity ?

Comment: I haven't developed this enough to post an answer - but I feel there is potentially a connection between Esau and Jakob and the ritual of Yom Kippur. The 2 goats. One is a scape goat which is cast out into the wilderness and bares the sins of the community - designated for "Azazel". The other stays within the community and is designated to the Lord and offered as a blood sacrifice. The garment of hair and being a hunter that spends time in the wilderness and handing over of birth right potentially lends itself to the scapegoat role

Answer (score 2):

## No, God may have respected him for it

That's my short answer, just to be concise. I'll explain...

### The Bible is "observant", not "biased" about hunting

Rather than copy-paste Bible verses, here is a great list of [verses about hunting](https://bible.knowing-jesus.com/topics/Hunting). Overall, it has no single-sided pro- or con- view, only that hunting is *hunting*.

But, here are a few verses to highlight...

- Amos neutrally connects a lion's (hunting animal) roar with catching prey (neutral view), then compares a lion to God Himself! (favorable view)

**Amos 3:4, 8** (NASB)

> Does a lion roar in the forest when he has no prey?
>
> Does a young lion growl from his den unless he has captured something?
>
> ...
>
> A lion has roared! Who will not fear?
>
> The Lord God has spoken! Who can but prophesy?

- Jesus is called a hunting animal, *Lion of Judah* (favorable view)

**Revelation 5:5** (NASB)

> and one of the elders *said to me, “Stop weeping; behold, the **Lion that is from the tribe of Judah**, the Root of David, has overcome so as to open the book and its seven seals.

- But, God also delivers His loved one's from the hunter's trap (adverse view)

**Psalm 91:3** (NASB)

> For it is He who delivers you from the snare of the trapper
>
> And from the deadly pestilence.

---

*It's related, but not directly to the main topic, so I'll include as an afterthought...*

## Warrior (similar to hunter)

Being a warrior is also viewed in a somewhat positive light. This isn't too far from being a hunter, which helps with a more rounded view when using "hermeneutics by cross-reference".

- Many Bible [verses describe God as a warrior](https://bible.knowing-jesus.com/topics/God-As-A-Warrior), so that can't be bad.
- Consider [David's "Mighty Men"](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Samuel%2023%3A8%E2%80%9338&version=NASB) who accompanied him

### David a Warrior: God told him *both* yes and no

- David was the champion warrior who helped Israel defeat the Philistines by killing Goliath ([1 Sam 17](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Samuel%2017&version=NASB)) and a "man after God's heart" ([1 Sam 13:14, Acts 13:22](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Samuel%2013%3A14%2C%20Acts%2013%3A22&version=NASB))
- God never rebuked David as a man of war, but wouldn't let David build the Temple ([1 Kings 8:18-19](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Kings%208%3A18-19&version=NASB), [1 Chron 28:1-7](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Chron%2028%3A1-7&version=NASB)).

God loved David, but wanted the Temple built by Solomon. The Bible only says this was because David was a man of war, but we know that Solomon was a man of peace. This wouldn't mean that "God doesn't like warriors", but that "God's Temple is a Temple of peace".

Comment: You've made your main point here, Esau's death, about something that's from outside the Bible, and which you don't actually give any time to explaining. At the very least you should explain where this story about Esau's death comes from, the Babylonian Talmud, and why you think it should be used by Christians (as your use of NT verses implies.)

Comment: you are totally right! thank you! editing

Comment: @curiousdannii I completely axed all my hard work because you were right, leaving it only on the topic of hunting. Is that sufficient?

Comment: Yeah that's better. But do bring it back, if you can write a little more about the Talmud. It's normal for Jewish users on this site to reference the Talmud, but it's rather uncommon for Christians, hence why I was suggesting an explanation of how the story appears in the Talmud and why you think it gives a good insight to Esau's character.

Comment: @curiousdannii Sir, I am at a loss! Professionalism demands that I decline because I am not studied in the Talmud, to my sorrow. I must limit the scope of my answer to the scope of my understanding. As much as I would like to have an opinion on it, because it is beyond my experience and expertise, my "opinion" wouldn't be an "educated/experienced" opinion, therefore only a "guess". I'd love to start researching the Talmud, and after ten years start answering from it. But, it would be unprofessional at this point. I'd love to hear what anyone else has to say though.

Comment: I think you’re on the right path when you bring Nimrod up. Explore the Hebrew word gibbor גּבּר which is used to describe Nimrod and consider who the gibborim are also referenced to be in the Bible. You will see a connection to giants and nephil נפל. Also then trace Nimrod’s lineage back to Noah’s sons and see who else shares lineage with him. The text also possibly says he BECAME hayah a gibbor. That then opens another study on the elohim and witchcraft magic. You don’t need to use the Talmud, Talmud uses DDS & LXX not MT so use DDS as it’s older and has agreeing texts in the LXX.

Comment: I feel like I need to clarify this in anticipation. Talmud doesn’t use the DSS obviously but a DSS “version” of the Tanakh. The MT comes far later and I have already stated my suspicion of the MT as being anti-Jesus. It has an incentive to be, given Jesus fits too well into the text. But now that we have the LXX AND the DSS we have two witnesses as opposed to just one from later period that also added diacritics or niqquds. We also have extrabiblical writings that seem to agree for the most part with the DSS which often times is a third witness. MT has its place but I have my reservations

Answer (score 0):

Esau’s mark (curse) was that of having reddish (eventually interpreted white hairy skin).  The Hebrew description of this ‘whitish’ skin condition is translated to lepracy as in the case of Miriam Moses’ sister and many other scriptures. Read Esau-Edomite Rome—The Hidden Identity of the Man of Sin by Dr. Beneyah Yashar’el…

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).